# Include ActiveReports 6 DLL in WebSite Build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, activereports

I have inherited a web site from a co-worker who retired and I wasn't brought up to speed with it before they left. It uses ActiveReports 6, which I have installed on my computer, but others don't have it on theirs. It was asked that I make it so the solution includes the ActiveReports 6 DLLs when I build the web site so that it doesn't have to be installed on every computer. Is this even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible not to install AR6 on the other machines and still run the AR6 application on them. This can be done by performing offline licensing of AR6 on the other build machines.

You may refer to the following blogs wherein detailed steps are discussed that might help you in meeting your requirement :

http://rajiitis.blogspot.in/2009/08/licensing-activereports-6.html
http://blogs.componentone.co.in/2011/08/09/licensing-a-build-machine-for-using-activereports-6/

Regards,
Mohita